# Categorical Variables Cox Proportional Hazards Model SPSS

Tags: categorical-data, spss, cox-model

How can I stratify individual categories for a variable when doing Cox models to see if a particular category within the variable is a significant predictor in SPSS? For example, the variable can be race, and I would like to see the influence of each (Asian, Caucasian, etc.) on survival. Would I need to separate each race into a different variable/column, code it as a binary value, and choose one to be a reference? Would I need to do this for all the possible combinations though? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in all regressions, not just Cox. With a multi-level categorical predictor, you can't ask whether an individual level is a "significant" predictor on its own. You can examine the contribution of the *entire* categorical predictor (whether *any* levels are associated with differences in outcome), and you can examine *differences* among specific levels with respect to associations with outcome.

> Would I need to separate each race into a different variable/column, code it as a binary value, and choose one to be a reference?

That's how the standard "treatment" or "dummy" coding of a categorical predictor works "under the hood." You don't have to do it yourself, and you don't have to re-run the model using each level individually as a reference, as the information about the differences between levels and their significance is present in the model's regression coefficients and the coefficient covariance matrix. I don't use SPSS, but it almost certainly has tools for doing pairwise comparisons among levels of a categorical predictor once the model is fit. It might go by a name something like "estimated marginal means." In R the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) is a widely used tools for such post-model analysis.